# break apart many javascript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have several javascript objects in a long array, for example:

```
[{"name": "bob", "values": {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}}, 
 {"name": "ted", "values": {"A": 4, "B": 5, "C": 6}},
                 ...
]
```

What is a clean and fast way to convert this array to:

```
[{"name": "bob", "A": 1},
 {"name": "bob", "B": 2},
 {"name": "bob", "C": 3},
 {"name": "ted", "A": 4},
 {"name": "ted", "B": 5},
 {"name": "ted", "C": 6},
         ...
]
```

I am somewhat new to javascript and am interested in the "right" way to approach this task.

Comment: Are you okay with using a library like LoDash to simplify your code?

Comment: Yes, I am ok with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate (a.k.a. "loop") through the array, and within each iteration, iterate through the 'values' object contained within it.

```
var from = [
        {"name": "bob", "values": {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}}, 
        {"name": "ted", "values": {"A": 4, "B": 5, "C": 6}}
    ],
    to = [],
    i, person, valueKey, newObj;

for (i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
    person = from[i];

    for (valueKey in person.values) {
        newObj = {};
        newObj.name = person.name;
        newObj[valueKey] = person.values[valueKey];

        to.push(newObj);
    }
}

console.log(to);
```

[Working example at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/paxolixuru/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

Using `LoDash`, you can do something like this:

```
var result = _.transform(people, function(memo, person) {
    var r = { name: person.name };
    _.each(person.values, function(number, letter) { r[letter] = number; });
    return memo.push(r);
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4w6mx0ha/).